# Replicate GitLab CI & Runner Functionality Locally?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In absence of network, on-site we can commit to local git repo but can't have gitlab-ci to compile project and early trobuleshoot.

How to have a localized gitlab-ci and gitlab-runner which can compile commits offline (*or alternate means) ?

Comment: Do you mean *"how do I run tests locally"*?

Comment: Nope *how to compile using .gitlab-ci.yml* as in actual gitlab website when offline.

Comment: That seems a bit backwards. That file should tell GitLab how to run your tests and compile the code etc. *the same as you do it locally*. Could you give some more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gitlab runner has an [exec](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/commands/README.md#gitlab-runner-exec) command which allows you to run the gitlab runner on your local machine with your local .gitlab-ci.yml configuration file.

> This command allows you to run builds locally, trying to replicate the CI
>   environment as much as possible. It doesn't need to connect to GitLab, instead
>   it reads the local .gitlab-ci.yml and creates a new build environment in
>   which all the build steps are executed.

Though if local network troubles are often you may consider installing the gitlab on premises and connect your own local gitlab runner to it so the work is automated.

Comment: Sounds really convincing. Is there any guide for `on-premisis gitlab with runner`

Comment: Thanks I got some video for [gitlab installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DSCpWaFcGY). I guess there would also be for others. Thank you Sir.